# CakePHP store array of id's in many-to-many table

Tags: arrays, cakephp, many-to-many, relationship

I'm having a problem with CakePHP. I try to set some data with the saveAll() function. I json_decode the following JSON string and pass the result to the saveAll() method.

```
{
    "SurveyAnswer":{
        "data":25,
        "data":45,
        "data":100
    },
    "GpsObservation":[
    {
        "latitude":1,
        "longitude":1
    },
    {
        "latitude":1,
        "longitude":1
    }
    ],
    "PeopleOption":[
    {
        "id":1
    },
    {
        "id":2
    }
    ]
}
```

The 'PeopleOption' table is the many-to-many relationship table between 'SurveyAnswer' and 'PeopleOptions'. As you can see I store some data in SurveyAnswer, which works perfect. However, the user is able to select multiple persons hence the 'PeopleOption' Many-to-Many table and CakePHP doesn't store those in the database.

The strange thing is: When I change the PeopleOption array into a JSON object, like this:

```
"PeopleOption": {
    "id":1
}
```

It works perfectly well, but obviously only for one record.

How can I pass along an array of id's that it has to store in the many-to-many relationship table 'PeopleOption'?

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While I've not been given an answer yet, I found the solution myself. When inserting an array of id's in a many to many table with the saveAll() function you should use a nested array inside a JSON object, like this:

```
"PeopleOption": {
   "PeopleOption":[
       3,
       14,
       7,
       etc,
   ]
}
```

Hope this helps any person who comes across the some problem I had!